# turtle_teleop_key node doesn't work properly

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Hi guys, I am new on ROS. I have been doing the ROS tutorials and I got stuck on the tutorial : ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics. After I run the node turtle_teleop_key, I am supposed to be able to move the turtle using the arrow keys but nothing happen when I hit the arrow keys. I am using the Hydro distro and I noticed that I got a short message after running the node like:
Reading from keyboard

Use arrow keys to move the turtle.

But on the tutorial the message is like this :

### [ INFO] 1254264546.878445000: Started node [/teleop_turtle], pid [5528], bound on [aqy], xmlrpc port [43918], tcpros port [55936], logging to [~/ros/ros/log/teleop_turtle_5528.log], using [real] time
Reading from keyboard

Use arrow keys to move the turtle.

Also, I selected the terminal window of turtle_teleop_key before pressing the arrow keys but nothing change
Please any input about this issue. Thanks a lot in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132711/turtle_teleop_key-node-doesn%27t-work-properly/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys, I found my mistake. The error was that I forgot to set up ROS_HOSTNAME  before running the node. The turtle is running now.
Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) with karma: 63 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0